# has_shortcode() - how to detect nested shortcode

Tags: php, shortcode

I'm using `has_shortcode()` to detect a shortcode, it works but not at all. If I put this specified shortcode inside another one the `has_shortcode()` function stops working.

```
has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'slider' )
```

For example:

```
[2col] //left column
[slider]
[2col_next] //right column
[slider]
[/2col]
```

The `has_shortcode()` function won't work in that case but if I use `[slider]` shortcode without `[2col]` it works perfect. This refers to every shortcode. I'm pretty sure that there's nothing wrong with my shortcodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$page_id = get_queried_object_id();
$page_object = get_page( $page_id );
if ( strpos($page_object->post_content, '[/slider]') )
```

Comment: Function ['get_page'](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page/) is deprecated since 3.5.0 use [get_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) instead.